# multiuser management in O365 python

Tags: python, graph, o365-flow

I was creating an application of office which contain multiple user credentials and do the tasks like emailing and adding calender events. I choosed [**O365**](https://pypi.org/project/O365/). All things were great here except. I could not save the credentials. like in other google products we pickle the creds.

```py
with open(f'account_data/{account_name}.pickle','wb') as stream:
    pickle.dump(account, stream)
```

but I error as

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'OAuth2Session.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

> I need to store multiple user keys and do some tasks. If you have any other module then tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

```py
from O365 import Account, MSGraphProtocol, message, FileSystemTokenBackend
def new_account(account_name):
    account = Account(credentials, scopes=scopes, )
    token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path='account_data', token_filename=f'{account_name}.txt')
    account.con.token_backend = token_backend
    account.authenticate()
    account.con.token_backend.save_token()

def load_account(account_name):
    account = Account(credentials, scopes=scopes, )
    token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path='account_data', token_filename=f'{account_name}.txt')
    account.con.token_backend = token_backend
    account.con.token_backend.load_token()
    if account.con.refresh_token():
        return account
```